# How do I get a bottom scrollbar tied to an overflowing div inside the body rather than on the entire body?

Tags: css, css-position, css-tables

I have a webpage with a long table on it. I want a scrollbar to be fixed to the bottom of the page that lets me scroll the table horizontally. I can do it with `overflow-x: auto;` on the body but this causes the whole page to scroll horizontally.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I should just use a jquery plugin that lets me customize the scrollbar with css.

github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar